# Access to path is denied when deleting folder

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, directory

I am working on WPF. I developed a WPF application in which the user can create and delete folders. Creation of folder is working fine, but in deletion there are issues in accessing the folder, even the drive. By following the steps mentioned below, I was able to change the owner and the permissions. But it still doesn't work:

1. Right-clicked folder.
2. Selected "Security" tab.
3. Selected "Advanced Security -> Owner" tab, then selected owner "Everyone" from existing list of owners.
4. In the "Permissions" Tab, I assigned "Everyone" to have full control in accesing the drive.

Code:

```
if (DXMessageBox.Show ("Are You Sure, you Want to Delete?", "Delete Item-Confirmation", MessageBoxButton.YesNo, MessageBoxImage.Question) == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
{
    try
    {
        int ID = (grid.SelectedItem as Name).PK_ID;
        string folderpath = @"F:/Delete/" +(grid.SelectedItem as Name).Name1;
        string foldername = (grid.SelectedItem as Name).Name1;
        File.Delete(folderpath);

        if (!Directory.Exists(folderpath))
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connection_string);
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("Delete From Names where PK_ID=" + ID + ";", con);
            comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            MessageBox.Show(folderpath);
            Refresh();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        DXMessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Check this out:- http://support.microsoft.com/kb/256614

Comment: `There are issues...`, let us know what your application says about these issues (and perhaps add the code that tries to delete the folder)

Comment: @Steve i posted code.

Comment: File.Delete(folderpath); - Did you try delete folder?

Comment: @Steve yes, it is throwing exception "Access to path f:\Delete is denied".

Comment: Are there still files in the folder? Do you try to delete a folder or a file? is Name1 an empty string perhaps>

Comment: @rene Name1:It is column name in database table of data type nvarchar. i want to delete both. Please read my question carefully, there are access to folder-path  is denied. Problem is to access a path of a folder. Code is correct.

Comment: I edited your question and fixed indentation.  There seemed to be one extra and unnecessary closing brace. Would appreciate if you would check.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I want to delete a folder, so i use`Directory.Delete(folderpath);` instead of using `File.Delete(folderpath);`

Thank you everyone specially to Rahul :)

Comment: You should mark this as an answer if it resolved your question.